# T-SQL Select where "IN" very bad Performance impact

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

when use the following code:

```
SELECT * INTO #StoreIdsPermision FROM (SELECT StoreId FROM dbo.FN_Inv_GetListOfStoreIdCheckPermission(15,3019)) StoreIdsPermision;

SELECT distinct

        Id,
        StoreName,
        ......,
        ......,

    from INV_Transactions
        inner join ....
        left outer join ....

    WHERE StoreId in (select Id from #StoreIdsPermision)
```

Execution time is 4 minutes.

and when use the same code with comma syntax in "WHERE IN" statement, the execution time is 3 seconds, why? and how fix that?

```
SELECT distinct

        Id,
        StoreName,
        ......,
        ......,

    from INV_Transactions
        inner join ....
        left outer join ....

    WHERE StoreId in (4,7,9,15,22,........)
```

NOTE: the Execution time for the following statement less than 1 second, and #StoreIdsPermision about 140 row only

```
SELECT * INTO #StoreIdsPermision FROM (SELECT StoreId FROM dbo.FN_Inv_GetListOfStoreIdCheckPermission(15,3019)) StoreIdsPermision;
```

Actual Execution Plan for Part 1
[image: Actual Execution Plan]

Actual Execution Plan for Part 2
[image: Actual Execution Plan]

Actual Execution Plan when use comma syntax
[image: Actual Execution Plan]

UPDATE 1:

VERY GOOD Suggestion from "Eponyme Web" Suggestion Number Two, when added SET FORCEPLAN ON In the First and SET FORCEPLAN OFF in The last Query, the Execution Time is Normal, what Happen?

UPDATE 2:

I replaced all inner join to left outer join and worked fine also without FORCEPLAN ON

Comment: How much time does `SELECT Id FROM #StoreIdsPermision` take when you run it alone?

Comment: less than 1 second

Comment: Please add 2 actual execution plans to your question

Comment: @MohamedElsayedAli `IN` doesn't affect performance. Missing indexes do. You haven't provided the table schemas, indexes or execution plans so it's not possible to say what's wrong. I'd bet that `#StoreIdsPermision.Id` isn't covered by an index, forcing the server to scan the entire `#StoreIdsPermision` table for each row in the outer query

Comment: I will attach actual execution plans.

Comment: Hard-coding the values is most likely generating an index seek on the execution plan, while using the SELECT is probably doing an left semi join on the records after being fetched from the other joins in your query. You will see this difference pretty clearly by analysing the execution plans on both selects. Please use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to share the plans.

Comment: #StoreIdsPermision about 140 row only

Comment: Sort distinct seems to be the most expensive part. Do you really want distinct?

Comment: Sort distinct in expensive in two query

Comment: When you use literal values the cardinality estimates will likely be more accurate than when you use a temp table. With the literals it is able to use the statistics to estimate each specific hardcoded `StoreId ` value and combine them. With the table it will use a different approach of histogram alignment that may be less accurate. Different estimates can cause different plans.

Comment: Solved By 1.  FORCEPLAN ON, 2. replace all inner join with left outer join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confirmed that the first part of the first query is not causing the issue ?

```
SELECT * 
INTO #StoreIdsPermision 
FROM 
    (SELECT StoreId 
     FROM dbo.FN_Inv_GetListOfStoreIdCheckPermission(15, 3019)) StoreIdsPermision;
```

If the above code is not the source of the performance issue, you can add an index to your #StoreIdsPermision temp table

```
CREATE INDEX sip1 ON #StoreIdsPermision (StoreId);
```

I would try two other things (always keeping the created index on the temp table)

1 - replacing your where clause with this one

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 from #StoreIdsPermision SIP WHERE INV_Transactions.StoreId  = SIP.StoreId)
```

2 - put a forceplan on at the beginning of the second query and a forceplan off at the end. 99.9% of the time the optimiser gets it right or at least right enough, but sometimes it doesn't. In you case I wouldn't expect such a difference in performance from the two approaches.

Comment: the Execution time for select into statement less than 1 second, and when add index for  #StoreIdsPermision  nothing new

Comment: @MohamedElsayedAli that doesn't mean much. Post the execution plans. Right now you haven't provided enough information to diagnose, nor proved that there's anything wrong with `IN`

Comment: i will attach actual execution plans

Comment: #StoreIdsPermision about 140 row only

Comment: @MohamedElsayedAli I added two more suggestions, for you to try. I don't believe you did anything wrong.

Comment: Why are you suggesting to create an index on temp table? Did you mean create index on INV_Transactions?

Comment: VERY GOOD Suggestion Number Two, when add SET FORCEPLAN ON In the First and SET FORCEPLAN OFF in The last Query, the Execution Time is Normal, what Happen?

Comment: @SalmanA The temp table is used in the next query so adding an index could have helped to get a more optimal plan. This is a common trick, but it usually make a difference on large temp tables.

Comment: @MohamedElsayedAli I don't know for sure. When you have temp tables involved the problem for the optimizer is not knowing in advance how big the temp tables are and thus not always selecting the optimum plan, it could be that the table's stats are not up to date also. But using temp tables in t-sql is perfectly valid (I find the code easier to read). One word of caution on using set forceplan some people have an allergic reaction to it, personnally I believe it exists because they're cases where it is needed the optimizer is very good but not perfect.

Comment: @EponymeWeb i replaced all inner join to left outer join and worked fine also without forceplan

Answer (score 0):

Normally it wouldn't be that bad, so it looks like the query will be 3 seconds because it's already been cached.

You can use below sql script get cache check query:

```
SELECT cplan.usecounts, cplan.objtype, qtext.text, qplan.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cplan
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS qtext
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qplan
where text like '%IN (4,7,9,15,22,........)%'
   or text like '% in (select Id from #StoreIdsPermision)%'
ORDER BY cplan.usecounts DESC
```

If temp table query not in cache and normal query in cache result then It explains why one takes four minutes and the other three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`where .... in ...(1,2,3)` is essentially executing `or` against each and every element in that list. The 3 minutes is the `(select Id from ...)` without an index. @EponymeWeb says build an index; yes, but check that  performance against `#StoreIdsPermission` as a permanent table with a permanent index. When you flush then refill that table be sure to rebuild statistics.